# setting limit to floatfield according to another floatfield

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I these fields in a Form:

```
demand = forms.FloatField(label='Demand:', min_value=0)
production_rate = forms.FloatField(label='Production rate:', min_value=0)
```

I need `producion_rate` to be greater than the `demand`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `clean` method of your Form:

```
class FormName(Form):
    demand = forms.FloatField(label='Demand')
    production_rate = forms.FloatField(label='Production rate')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if cleaned_data['production_rate'] <= cleaned_data['demand']: # Use '<' instead of '<=' to allow equal values
            raise ValidationError('Your error message')
        return cleaned_data
```